# Разделение границ точек в matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Здравствуйте!
Занимаюсь визуализацией данных в Python(у меня установлена Anaconda, работаю в jupyter notebook) с pandas и matplotlib. Почему-то matplotlib не отрисовывает границы точек, а рисует их одним сплошным пятном.
То есть когда я загружаю чужой notebook, в нем все выглядит прилично :
[image: Точки здорового человека]
,а когда начинаю исполнять этот notebook, получаю такое
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Никаких специальных параметров для matplotlib,насколько я вижу,в notebook-ах не задается.Я проверял корректность установки matplotlib,пробовал менять версии дистрибутива,менять браузер по умолчанию - не помогает.Теперь вот думаю, может дело в том, что у меня Windows 7 и старый DirectX?

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете попробовать сделать

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = np.random.rand(10)
y = np.random.rand(10)
z = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)

plt.scatter(x, y, s = 80, c = z, marker="*")

verts = list(zip(\[-1., 1., 1., -1.\], \[-1., -1., 1., -1.\]))

plt.show()
```

[image: Пример]

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [np.random.normal() for i in range(100000)]
y = [np.random.normal() for i in range(100000)]
plt.scatter(x, y, marker='o',edgecolor='black',linewidth='1');
```

`edgecolor` задает цвет границ точек, `linewidth` - задает толщину